# Transform animation on element causes it to overlap fixed position header in iOS only

Tags: ios, css, css-position, transform

I'm building a site that makes use of a card flip animation [found here](http://callmenick.com/post/css-transitions-transforms-animations-flipping-card) and has a fixed position nav menu. When the card flips in any browser on iOS it gets pushed in front of the fixed nav menu. It works fine in any other browser I've tested so far including Chrome on an Android phone.

I've found a number of reasons this may be happening ranging from hardware acceleration issues to transforms taking place on a different "plane" than flat elements (ignoring z-index). I've tried applying `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` to the nav menu and using translateZ to change the position along with applying a few other hacks that haven't worked yet.